# Adding CSS animation every x seconds with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a function that is updating text on my homepage every 3 seconds, and I'd like to have the text fade in/fade out when it transitions. I have really simple keyframe animations that handle this (fadeIn/fadeOut), but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to tackle this. Any chance someone can give me some pointers? Thank you!

```
  changeHomeText() {
    var count = 0;
    const phrases = ["Phrase 1", "Phrase 2", "Phrase 3", "Phrase 4"];
    var text = document.getElementById('dyntext');
    text.innerHTML = phrases[0];

    setInterval(function() {
      if (count == phrases.length) {
        count=0;
      }
      text.innerHTML = phrases[count];
      count++;
    }, 3000);

  }

***CSS***

@keyframes fadeIn {
   from {opacity: 0;}
   to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
   from {opacity: 1;}
   to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: "*I have really simple keyframe animations that handle this (fadeIn/fadeOut)*" Can you [edit] your question to include them? Please see how to create a [MRE] with all of the relevant code so we can help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten sure, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you are animating the text, this is a function that will work for ever and called every 3 seconds to update the Text

```
var count = 0;
var phrases = ["Phrase 1", "Phrase 2", "Phrase 3", "Phrase 4"];
function changeHomeText() {
    var text = document.getElementById('dyntext');
    text.innerHTML = phrases[count];
    if (count == phrases.length) {
        count=0;
    }
    text.innerHTML = phrases[count];
    count++;

    setTimeout(function () {
        changeHomeText();
    }, 3000);
}
changeHomeText();
```

you can do whatever you want inside your function and it will repeat itself every 3 seconds.